# angular expression working inside a script tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, hybrid-mobile-app

How do I get an angular expression working inside a script tag... I am pretty new to this and need help? 
Here is an example of my java script code:

```
    <script id="modal-2.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div class="modal transparent">
<div class="card">
<i class="icon ion-ios7-close close-modal" ng-click="closeModal(2)"></i>
<div class="item item-divider">
{{card.title}}
</div> 
<div class="item item-text-wrap">
{{card.details}}
</div>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

Here is an example of my array:

```
.controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicModal, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

  $scope.cardss = 
  {id:1, title:'Frank', src:'img/Frank.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  {id:2, title:'Generali', src:'img/Generali.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  {id:3, title:'John Lewis', src:'img/JohnLewis.png',details:'This will be the products description!'},
  ];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special wrt use of AngularJS expressions inside partial templates.

As already said your model is actually array - so you'll have to iterate through the items using [ng-repeat](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="card in cards">
        Card id: {{card.id}}
        Card title: {{card.title}}
        Card details: {{card.details}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please see working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw2e06h9/) example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you can use your template:

```
<div ng-include src="'modal-2.html'"></div>
```

or use it with a button:

```
<button ng-click="currentTpl='modal-2.html'">Show Modal</button>
<div ng-include src="currentTpl"></div>
```

The **expression in the template then works as is usual**.
Here is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvqfdotd/2/)**.